# How to check if all the drivers are installed correctly? And what is the use of graphic card in ubuntu, is it now a waste?

Tags: drivers, graphics, intel-graphics

Recently I removed windows completely from my Dell Inspiron(did by mistake but now I am enjoying Ubuntu) and installed ubuntu 18.04.2 LTS on it.

I am a beginner and want to check if all the drivers are installed correctly.

Further, I want to know what is the use of graphics card in Ubuntu. I have an Intell graphics card, how can I install its graphics card and what are its benefits.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

> I am a beginner and want to check if all the drivers are installed correctly.

With Linux, drivers are generally shipped as part of the kernel, and you don't really have to worry about it. There's a few instances where this is the case, like for new, yet unsupported wifi cards, and some proprietary drivers for video cards.

If everything works, stop worrying. If something is not working like you expect, investigate the part that is not working.

> Further, I want to know what is the use of graphics card in Ubuntu. I have an Intell graphics card, how can I install its graphics card and what are its benefits.

Intel graphic cards is supported by the stock kernels. The benefits of hardware acceleration is the same in Linux as any other OS - offloading video playback, offloading 3D operations, and so forth.